# Spark Custom Partioner vs SortByKey Functionality

Tags: apache-spark, rdd, bigdata

Given a dataset of [K,V] and a need to join based on key which method provides the best method for ensuring data locality/speed a Custom Partitioner/Hash Partitioner or using the SortBy() method followed by the join method? And why is one method more performant over the other?

Additionally if you have the majority of keys being the same key does this affect the method choice?

Case 1

```
val rdd = sc.parallelize(Seq(("gh5", "id1"), ("gh4", "id1"), ("gh5", "id2"),("gh5", "id3"))

val sorted = rdd.sortBy(_._1)

val joined = sorted.join(sorted)
```

Case 2

```
val rdd = sc.parallelize(Seq(("gh5", "id1"), ("gh4", "id1"), ("gh5", "id2"),("gh5", "id3"), ...)

val custom_partitioned = rdd.partitionBy(100)).persist()

val joined = custom_partitioned.join(custom_partitioned)
```

Answer (score 2):

If you consider only `join` performance and assume that both `sorted` and `custom_partitioned` RDDs are cached there should be practical difference whatsoever. Both:

```scala
rdd.sortBy(_._1)
```

and

```scala
rdd.partitionBy(somePartitione)
```

will result in partitioned RDDs and this partitioning will be leveraged by subsequent `cogroup`.

If you take into account a whole process including `sortBy` / `partitionBy` then the second option should be cheaper because it doesn't require initial statistics and local sort. Sorting based approach can preferable in some cases when you expect highly skewed keys distribution but it won't help you in case of very low cardinality. If you expect that this may be the case you may consider Cartesian product followed by filter but this should be used as a last resort.

Comment: When there is going to be a highly skewed distribution is SortBy the best way to ensure data locality/performance on the join or is there in fact a better way of performing the same function (Other than those proposed).

Comment: After shuffle with the same partitioner each operation will be local by definition. And choice of the partitioner (`RangePartioner` is used for sorting) depends on your data and actual distribution. There is no single universal solution.If you know that data is organized in a specific manner you create custom partitioner which reflects that.